# Looping through two arrays simultaneously and printing in Handlebars Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two arrays `NOVNoticeTypeName` and `NOVNumber`, they both have the same number of elements, now I want to loop through one of them and print the values side by side as below:

```
{{#each  v.NOVNoticeTypeName as |nntn index|}}
  {({{v.NOVNoticeTypeName.[index]}} {{v.NOVNumber.[index]}})
{{/each}}
```

I understand looping is a mess in the Ember handlebars.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know ember, but if you access the index only with brackets? `v.NOVNoticeTypeName[index]`

Comment: No that doesn't work friend but thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't share your opinion that looping is a mess in Ember templates. Would be great if you don't put such opinions as a facts. Especially if it comes without any argument.

What you want to achieve could be done with a combination of an `{{each}}` loop and a template helper. As your example already shows `{{each}}` loop yields the current value and index. You can't access an array element directly using the index as in JavaScript `array[index]` in an Ember template but you could achieve the same using a template helper. A template helper, lets call it `{{object-at}}` that gets an index as first and an array as second argument and returns `array[index]`.

Lets see an example how that would work:

```
{{#let (array 'a' 'b' 'c') as |letters|}}
  {{#let (array '1' '2' '3') as |numbers|}}
    <ul>
      {{#each letters as |letter index|}}
        {{letter}} {{object-at index numbers}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/let}}
{{/let}}
```

Such a template helper wouldn't be to complex. But you don't have to worry at all, cause it's already available as part of [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers).

Comment: Jelhan's answer is to the point. If it helps, this is a [small guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) about looping list in Ember template